# Specific linear classifier in TensorFlow: input element as vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

How can I implement such linear classifier in TensorFlow:

```
x1*w1 + x2*w2 + x3*w3 = y_pred,
```

where x1, x2, x3 - vectors and w1, w2 and w3 - scalars?

I have nice tutorial for case where x1, x2, x3 - scalars ([link](https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/linear-models/linear-classifier#0.-Import-the-required-libraries:)),

but for case where x1, x2, x3 are vectors I have no realization ideas.

***UPDATE***

That is I am trying to implement the following model:

```
x1*w1+ x2*w1+x3*w1+x4*w2+x5*w2+x6*w2+x7*w3+x8*w3+x9*w3=y_pred, 
where x1..x9 and w1..w9 are scalars.
```

Comment: Suspicious... I think weights (`w1`, `w2`, and `w3`) are matrices.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi maybe the labels are also vectors? ...

Comment: @meTchaikovsky It depends. Usually, model's `prediction` in deep learning means probability distribution over classes. Thus, it is a vector with dimension of the number of classes. More practically, model's prediction is matrix with shape of `size_of_batch * number_of_classes`.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi you are right, I haven't thought about this.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky Are you who wrote this question? I do not know what you exactly want to do. If you give me details, I think I can help you.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi No, I'm not ...

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi thank you for your interest! I have updated my question.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky thank you for your interest! I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is ill-posed. You say you want x_1, x_2, x_3 to be vectors, however it's not clear what you would do with w_1, w_2, w_3. There are two possibilities.

- If you want to keep them as *scalars*, as your question seems to imply, then the model is not really a vector model, you're just doing the same scalar operation on all the entries of the x vectors, but at once. This is equivalent to a scalar model.
- Otherwise, you can define w_1, w_2, w_3 as matrices, or row vectors, if the label is scalar. In this case, there is no reason to write the equation as you wrote it, because you could stack the xs in a single vector and the ws in a single vector and write wx = y. In any case, this is a multivariate linear regression, of which you can find many examples, and tutorials on how to solve it in Tensorflow and Torch.

#### Update, given OP's clarification

In your comment, you now say you're interested in solving the following equation:

`w1*(x1 + x2 + x3) + w2*(x4 + x5 + x6) + w3*(x7 + x8 + x9) == y`

where all variables are scalars. Note that the x variables are known, so we can define (a simple arithmetic operation):

`z1 = x1 + x2 + x3;  z2 = x4 + x5 + x6;  z3 = x7 + x8 + x9`

And the equation becomes

`w1*z1 + w2*z2 + w3*z3 = y`.

So this is more like a linear algebra question rather than a tensorflow/torch question, because this equation can be solved analytically, and does not require numerical fitting. However, it is still ill-defined, because it has 3 unknowns (w1, w2, w3) for one linear equation. So it will not have a unique solution, but a two-dimensional linear space of solutions (it identifies a plane in the 3-dimensional w-space). To get some solutions, you can arbitrarily decide to set, for example, w1 = w2 = 0, from which you automatically get w3 = z3/y. Then do the same for the other two, and you'll get three different and linearly independent solutions.

Hope this helps. In summary, you don't need code at all.

#### Second update (from comment)

Why does it need to solved using optimization? If the problem is as you presented it, it clearly does not. Unless you mean you have many values for the Xs and Ys. In that case, you're doing multivariate linear regression. MLR can be solved using ordinary least squares, see for example https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer! I want to keep w_1, w_2 and w_3 as scalars. I think I did not explain the meaning of the task too clearly. I am trying to implement the following model: x1*w1+ x2*w1+x3*w1+x4*w2+x5*w2+x6*w2+x7*w3+x8*w3+x9*w3=y_pred, where x1..x9 and w1..w9 are scalars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question is devoted to one of the tasks of machine learning related to the selection of weight coefficients. This problem is not solved using linear algebra, but using optimization methods

Comment: Why does it need to solved using optimization? If the problem is as you presented it, it clearly does not. Unless you mean you have *many* values for the Xs and Ys. In that case, you're doing multivariate linear regression. MLR can be solved using ordinary least squares, see for example https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9

Answer (score 2):

The linear multiclass classifier to be implemented:

`pred = w1 * (x1 + x2 + x3) + w2 * (x4 + x5 + x6) + w3 * (x7 + x8 + x9)`

in which all variables are scalars.

In this model, **since `pred` is a scalar, you cannot use cross-entropy loss for training the classifier** (`pred` is not a distribution). **You have to treat it as a regression problem.**

Example dataset

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.ones((100, 3)) # for w1
x2 = np.ones((100, 3)) * 2 # for w2
x3 = np.ones((100, 3)) * 3 # for w3

# set(y) is {0, 1, 2, 3}, corresponds to the four class labels 
y = np.random.randint(0, 4, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Example `tensorflow` code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

tf.reset_default_graph()

f1 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f1')
f2 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f2')
f3 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f3')

target = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 1], name='target')

# the three scalars
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w3 = tf.get_variable('w3', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

pred_1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f1, w1), axis=1)
pred_2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f2, w2), axis=1)
pred_3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f3, w3), axis=1)

# till now the linear classifier has been constructed 
# pred = w1(x1 + x2 + x3) + w2(x4 + x5 + x6) + w3(x7 + x8 + x9)
pred = tf.add_n([pred_1, pred_2, pred_3])

# treat it as a regression problem
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - target))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-5)
updates = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for t in range(50):
        loss_val, _ = sess.run([loss, updates], 
                               feed_dict={f1: x1, f2: x2, f3: x3, target: y})
        print(t, loss_val)
```

Below is a simple example uses cross-entropy loss for training a multiclass classifier. As you can notice, this model is a neural network model

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 

x1 = np.ones((100, 3)) # for w1
x2 = np.ones((100, 3)) * 2 # for w2
x3 = np.ones((100, 3)) * 3 # for w3

y = np.random.randint(0, 4, 400).reshape(100, 4)

tf.reset_default_graph()

f1 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f1')
f2 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f2')
f3 = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 3], name='f3')

target = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 4], name='target')

# the three scalars
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w3 = tf.get_variable('w3', shape=[1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[3, 4], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

pred_1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f1, w1), axis=1)
pred_2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f2, w2), axis=1)
pred_3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(f3, w3), axis=1)

pred = tf.stack([pred_1, pred_2, pred_3], axis=1)
pred = tf.matmul(pred, w)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=target, logits=pred)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-5)
updates = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for t in range(50):
        loss_val, _ = sess.run([loss, updates], 
                               feed_dict={f1: x1, f2: x2, f3: x3, target: y})
        print(t, loss_val)
```

Comment: Thank you! I need some time to test your solution

Comment: what will change in the code if I need to solve the problem of not binary classification, but the problem of classification into four classes?

Comment: thank you! please explain why you increased the number of weights from three to four? after all, the number of feature vectors is three, so there should be three weighting factors

Comment: @V.Gai sorry, I misunderstood your model, I have edited my answer :)

Comment: @V.Gai Hi V.Gai, actually, I'm not satisfied with my answer, basically, I don't really understand your model. did you mean you still want to use `x1 * w1 + ... + x9 * w3 = y` for multiclass classification? I have to say this model is kind of weird ......

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to implement just such a strange model. Your code describes a regression model and a two-layer network, not a linear classifier

Comment: @V.Gai Hi V.Gai, I have updated my answer, basically, because `pred` is a scalar, to do multi-class classification, you have to treat it as a regression problem.

Comment: Thank you! but I think that your model pred = w1 * (x1 + x2 + x3) + w2 * (x4 + x5 + x6) + w3 * (x7 + x8 + x9) does not match the model described in the question. pred in this model - vector, also feature values in the model do not add up.

Answer (score 2):

I used created an array that looks like [w1, w1, w1, w2, w2, w2 ...] and multiplied it (element-wise) by x before summing all terms up. I could not get model.fit to work so I copied the `train_step` code from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced. It seems to work just fine. I left my test code at the bottom for you to inspect.

This makes use of tensorlfow 2.0 and the intergration with keras models

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

print(tf.executing_eagerly())

class ProductAdd(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProductAdd, self).__init__()
        self.vars = list(np.empty([3])) # Creates an empty list (same as [ , , ])
        for i in range(3):
            self.vars[i] = tf.Variable(      # Creates 3 variables to act as weights 
                np.random.standard_normal(), # Assigns variables random value to start
                 name='var'+str(i))          # Names them var0 var1...

    def call(self, x):
        extended_vars = [self.vars[int(np.floor(i/3))] # "Extends" var array to look like:
                          for i in range(9)]           # [w1, w1, w1, w2, w2, w2, w3, w3, w3]
        return np.sum(np.multiply(x, extended_vars))   # Perfoms element-wise multiplication on x and sums

loss_object = MeanSquaredError()    # Create loss and optimizer
optimizer = Adam()

@tf.function                                        # This function perfoms trains the model
def train_step(images, labels):                     # I got it from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:                   
    predictions = model(images)                     
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

model = ProductAdd()

for _ in range(100):
    train_step([1.0, 2.0 ,3.0 ,4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [0.0])

print(model([1.0, 2.0 ,3.0 ,4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]).numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you! your code has limitations that in the optimization process w1_1 = w1_2 = w1_3 and w2_1 = w2_2 = w2_3 and w3_1 = w3_2 = w3_3 ? or all of the weighting factor (nine items) are optimized separately?

Comment: There still is only three variables to be optimized as created in `__init__`. It is only in `call` these variables get temporarily cloned to complete the function. These clones are only in the `call` scope and are not saved as model variables sostill only remains three variables in the model.

Comment: Can you give the results of running the command "print(model([1.0, 2.0 ,3.0 ,4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]).numpy())" here?